# A Text value change on Powerpoint by using OpenXml doesn't fit

Tags: vb.net, powerpoint, openxml

I use OpenXml for creating custom powerpoint presentation in this way: I put a keyword on the presentation, I found it during process with OpenXml and change the text value. Everything work fine but the fit option doesn't work at first. 
The text box has options "Autofit: Shrink text on overflow; Wrap text in shape: On"
After my process, the new text appear on the right place but the autofit is not done, I need to click on the text box and make a input for see the autofit work. I think that PowerPoint only check option after a modification.

What I want is the autofit option is called at the end of the process. Can anyone help me?

I hope you understand what I want to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible using just OpenXML. The `<a:normAutofit/>` tag is used by a client application, such as PowerPoint, to render the text larger or smaller, as needed. OpenXML doesn't actually render anything, so until the client does, it will just read the text as if it is not auto-fitted.

There are a few options to think of to control this - none of them great however. One would be to use VSTO or VBA in PowerPoint to check all shapes on PPTX open and if they have a AutoFit tag, to re-render them. A second way would be to do all the font measurements yourself based on the shape's width & height and then set the font scale to the appropriate percentage. Another would be to make a textbox large enough to fit the largest amount of text you will ever insert and then turn autofit off.

Sorry this doesn't really help you immediately. I've done tons of research on this particular subject and it's all bad news.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, apparently you found the same informations than me. I thought about to do all the font measurements by myself but it's become a little bit complicate for a simple option. At the end, the solution that I created is to use cut the entry string if it is too big for the shape. Thanks once again for your research.

Comment: I've also researched the problem and found the following: If you remove the <a:normAutoFit/> from the <a:bodyPr/> tag then Powerpoint  renders the textbox again if you open the document.

Comment: @Hans: I just tested this and it didn't work. In fact, it doesn't work with or without `<a:normAutofit/>`. Also, even if it did slightly work (for example, you set it was rendered in the client) and then you re-edited the `<a:t>` tag to have a whole lot of text, the `fontScale="85000" lnSpcReduction="10000"` in `<a:normAutofit/>` are not used. It needs to be re-rendered again in the client and then those two properties will change.

Comment: Dug up this old thread to say it's easier to replace all instance of something with the same text (e.g. `<whitespace>` replaced with `<whitespace>`); that will force each slide to re-render after you add `<a:normAutofit/>`!

Comment: tried adding    run153.Text = new A.Text(run153.InnerText.Replace(run153.Text.Text, "your text"));  after adding the bodyproperties to the shape containing the normAutoFit tag but it failed.. how can I do this? @Still